# При выборе слайдшоу для фона рабочего стола KDE в openSUSE повисает Plasmashell

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse

Железо: HP Mini 210-2204er, система: openSUSE Leap-15.0 KDE.
При попытке сменить обои на слайдшоу система (Plasmashell) наглухо повисает.

ПКМ на рабочем столе, из меню выбрать "Настроить рабочий стол". Тип комнаты указать "просмотр папки", тип обоев "слайдшоу" из папки. После нажатия кнопки "применить" всё виснет, и больше на рабочий стол не выйти даже после перезагрузки.

Мышь не реагирует на клики, с клавиатуры можно только сменить консоль <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1..6</kbd>.
Спасает только:

```
rm ~ / .config / plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
killall plasmashell && plasmashell &
```

У других пользователей openSUSE на другом железе проблема не повторилась.